# Blender: Scale a group of vertices using python

Tags: python, vertices

I have a mesh made of 94 groups of 4 vertices:
[image: mesh]

I need to scale each group of vertices by a decreasing factor (from 100% to 0%).

I tried two different ways to do that, the first is based on the same function called when using the "scale command" via user interface:

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(
value=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 
constraint_axis=(False, False, False), 
constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', 
mirror=False, 
proportional='DISABLED', 
proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
proportional_size=1)
```

to begin, I tried to scale the first four vertices:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")

verts = obj.data.vertices
obj.data.vertices[0].select=True
obj.data.vertices[1].select=True
obj.data.vertices[2].select=True
obj.data.vertices[3].select=True


bpy.ops.transform.resize(
    value=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 
    constraint_axis=(False, False, False), 
    constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', 
    mirror=False, 
    proportional='DISABLED', 
    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
    proportional_size=1)
```

running the code in object mode with my mesh selected, just switches the enviroment to edit mode and nothing else, however if I manually select four vertices and run this script, it scales the four selected vertices correctly.
so.. why is `obj.data.vertices[i].select=True` completely useless? and how can I correctly select the vertices in order to get `bpy.ops.transform.resize()` correctly work on them?

I also tried to use bmesh library as it was recommended in most of the forums and guides I visited.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
import mathutils

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
face = bm.faces.active

vertices=[bm.verts[0],bm.verts[1],bm.verts[2],bm.verts[3]]

# Scale
scale = mathutils.Vector((0.2,0.2,0.2))
bmesh.ops.scale(
            bm,
            vec=scale,
            verts=vertices
            )

# Show the updates in the viewport
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

this script actually does something: it scales the coordinates of the first four vertices. this means that for each vertex I pass to that function, its position is scaled respect to the origin of the scene ( the point (0,0,0) ).
But I want it to be scaled respect to the center of the four vertices, as it would be if I manually select the vertices and apply the `bpy.ops.transform.resize()` function.

So, in the first case, how can I tell to "Blender" to select vertices in order to apply the `bpy.ops.transform.resize()` function?

And in the latter case, how can I make it to scale respect to the center of the four vertices instead of the center of the image?

Comment: Do you have the pivot point set to 3dcursor? Try `bpy.context.space_data.pivot_point = 'MEDIAN_POINT'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer a more low level solution. This particular approach requires the object to be in Object Mode, but a small change using Bmesh would let you do it in edit mode. This will give you some insight I hope.

[image]

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

# replace this with reference to your object.
obj = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve']

def get_average(vert_range):
    med = Vector()
    for vert in vert_range:
        vec = vert.co
        med = med + vec
    return med / len(vert_range)

verts = obj.data.vertices
num_verts = len(verts)
scale = 1 / (num_verts / 4)
j = 0
for i in range(0, num_verts, 4):
    mid = get_average(verts[i:i+4])
    for k in range(i, i+4):
        verts[k].co = verts[k].co.lerp(mid, 1-(j*scale))
    j += 1
```

[image]

For every 4 verts, it finds their average, and scales those verts towards that average by an increasing value every 4 verts. I may have reversed the direction so instead of `1-(j*scale)` you might want `(j*scale)`

---

for completeness A Bmesh solution, this works in edit mode

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

def get_average(vert_range):
    med = Vector()
    for vert in vert_range:
        vec = vert.co
        med = med + vec
    return med / len(vert_range)

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

verts = bm.verts
num_verts = len(verts)
scale = 1 / (num_verts / 4)
j = 0
for i in range(0, num_verts, 4):
    mid = get_average(verts[i:i+4])
    for k in range(i, i+4):
        verts[k].co = verts[k].co.lerp(mid, 1-(j*scale))
    j += 1

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

As you can see you were going in the right direction.

Comment: In the end I made it work moving the four vertices along the vector pointing from the middle of the four vertices to coordinates (0,0,0), then scaling them and moving them back along the same vector (with opposite direction).
But your solution is exactly what I was looking for to scale the four vertices in place, and in fact it is more correct and it works independently of the approach being with or without bmesh, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, I liked the question, it's useful to have more than one solution to think about.

Comment: As you could see I am a little "newbie" to Blender, so I'd ask you another tip: How do you turn on the vertex enumeration like shown in the second image you posted? It could turn very useful anytime I need to quickly understend how to apply scripts to my meshes

Comment: There's a default `bpy.app.debug = True` (but I find it hard to see wtthout a polygon background on the index, so there's an addon for it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/show-mesh-vertices-id/27820#27820

Answer (score 2):

vertex selection using `obj.data.vertices[i].select=True`should be done in OBJECT mode

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")

verts = obj.data.vertices
l = int(len(verts)/4)
for i in range(l) :

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    obj.data.vertices[i*4].select=True
    obj.data.vertices[i*4+1].select=True
    obj.data.vertices[i*4+2].select=True
    obj.data.vertices[i*4+3].select=True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(
        value=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 
        constraint_axis=(False, False, False), 
        constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', 
        mirror=False, 
        proportional='DISABLED', 
        proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
        proportional_size=1)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")    


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! selecting vertices in edit mode was actually the problem that prevented my script to correctly apply the resize

Comment: @MircoNani you are welcome