# Blender Python: Where do I get an Image with all the indices for the edges and faces of a cube?

Tags: python

I just need to know the index numbers of certain edges and faces in a cube in blender. 
Is there anywhere a diagram of that? Or can this be shown in blender as e.g. the length of an edge.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/show-mesh-vertices-id (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender doesn't normally display the indices information but it does have a debugging feature that can display them. To enable debugging you type `bpy.app.debug = True` into [blender's python console](http://www.blender.org/manual/extensions/python/console.html). Once enabled you will find an indices option in the mesh display panel of the properties region (press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the region) while in edit mode. Only the indices of selected items will be shown and your [selection mode](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html) will define whether vertex, edge or face info will be displayed.

[image]