# See number of vertices you selected

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have a mesh and when I access edit mode I can select a vert, but how can I see what verts it is? Because the "Verts:1/2712" will always stay 1.
I don't want to see how many I have selected, but the number of the one I have selected.
So when I have a mesh with 2715 vertices, and when I select the last, then I want to see: '2715'.

A screen of when I want to see the vert:

[image]

Comment: Please use the built in uploader for images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I think you have it correct, in the photo you uploaded, you do have one vert selected. Shift select a second vert to see it change to 2

Comment: ? Thats not my question. I don't want to see how many I have selected, but the number of the one I have selected. So when I have a mesh with 2715 vertices, and when I select the last, then I want to see: '2715'

Comment: press numpad period

Comment: Maybe this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/show-mesh-vertices-id?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  or this: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Index_Visualiser

Comment: @cegaton what do u mean?