# Dragging center point of cube won't drag all edges to corners with it

Tags: vertices

I'm so sorry if this is a horribly asked question but I am very new so I do not know all the terminology yet. I however do have pictures so that I can show the problem.

What I have now:
[image]

What I want is instead to have the left and right corners to form edges like:
[image]

But right now that only happens to only 2 of the corners. How do I get it to drag all 4 of the corners when I translate the center vertex?

EDIT: It appears the corners that this happens will change depending on my shading
Rendered: [image]
The corners that do not follow are next to each other now.

All others: Above, opposite corners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your faces are non-planar ([read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56764/30849)) and therefore need to be converted to triangles to be displayed (Blender will do this without telling us).

[image]
<sup>Showing us the render wires, make the triangulation apparent.</sup>

It is possible to trick Blender into triangulating the nonplanar quads in a different order.

1. Remove the faces in question and recreate them with triangles.
   [image]
2. Select the adjacent faces *in the correct order* and join them with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.
   [image]
   Note, that the correct order is dependant on the vertex index which can be shown only with [debug options enabled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3253/30849).

But this is not useful. If you want the area to have an edge explicitly define it with the correct topology.

[image: correct topology]

---

In the reference video, the same behaviour occurs.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! However I was wondering if it was possible to make it default to the different order? For example, [this video](https://youtu.be/OITWiN8Dplo?t=55s) shows that he could simply transform the vertex without needing to add edges or trick blender.

Comment: @Vuninja Check out the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around which is to just connect vertex path (Ctrl+V -> C). If anyone else has a better solution as this adds more edges, please answer.